# React Bootstrap Tab rendering issue with d3.js bar graph

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, react-bootstrap

So I am working on a ReactJS/Redux project where I have a set of 3 tabs(A,B,C) in that order (from React Bootstrap). Each of these tabs contains a graph written with d3.js. I have horizontal/vertical bar graphs, and a line chart. However, the vertical bar graphs, which are on the A and C tab, has issues rendering on C. It only works when I transition from A tab to C tab. If I go from B to C the bar graph shows up, but without the bars filled in ( the labels, number values show up). It seems that it is having some issue with rendering. When I switch the first tab - so swap A and C, the graph on C starts working while the one on A starts failing. The other d3.js components (the line and horizontal bar charts) are working fine at the moment. Even inspecting the application with dev tools shows no issue. Has anyone had an issue with this/know a solution to this? Any help would be appreciated as my team and I have spent a day trying to fix this.

Comment: This question in unanswerable without code.

Comment: It is a work environment so I am not sure I can post the code right now. Let me see what I can do.

Comment: One idea might be to make sure the graphs render once right away then use css display to hide them instead of actually removing the dom with react. Also consider the possibility of an async race condition with a react callback or hook.

Comment: Ok thank you! I am using React Bootstrap and have the tabs mount immediately, so the former should have been taken care of - I am not sure if it renders it on app launch and hides it or renders every time that you switch tabs, but I suspect the latter. I know react bootstrap also gives issues with tabs and leaflet maps sometimes - would you recommend any other tab component libraries from npm that might not suffer from this issue? I will look into the async race condition as well.